# calling variable in bootstrap alert php

Tags: php, html, css

I want to call $score into bootstrap alert but how do I call it correctly?.
I'm really a beginner

```
if ($score >= $threshold)
        echo "<div class="alert alert-success solid alert-square"><strong></strong></div>";
        echo $score."% Match";
else
        echo $score. "% Didn't match";
```

Comment: Watch your quotes: `"<div class="` won't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just build your data use `if..else` then echo it like this

```
if ($score >= $threshold) {
    $css_class = 'success';
    $alertMsg = $score."% Match";
} else {
    $css_class = 'danger';
    $alertMsg = $score."% Didn't match";
}
echo "<div class="alert alert-".$css_class." solid alert-square">
<strong> ".$alertMsg." </strong></div>";

// Note the concatenation
// "some html data". $variable . "some more html data"
```